# Chef & git ssh authentication woes. Bitbucket

Tags: git, ssh, chef-infra, bitbucket

Edit:  My working solution based on the answer below.

```
    include_recipe 'chef-vault'
include_recipe 'build-essential'

#installation of git
package 'git' do
  action :install
end

repo = 'emrwebapp'

application "/root/#{repo}" do
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  git "/root/#{repo}" do
    repository "git@bitbucket.org:sgreen22/#{repo}.git"
    deploy_key chef_vault_item(:credentials, 'git')['bitbucketKey']
  end
end
```

'-1 guy' - fanks! Have a nice day now.

I'm new to chef and am trying to clone a repo to complete a simple learning task i set myself.

I've followed many tutorials and tried a plethora of suggestions but still unable to clone the repo due to public key error.

I'm replicating steps on a local terminal to make sure that I've not messed up the url or anything.

I've:

Created a new key ensuring no password set, uploaded the public key to bitbucket ad tested the key using ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org from local machine.

I've then added this key to a chef vault, verified it's there and visible.

Then using chef I'm copying the key to a location on the client node and then attempting to clone the repo.

Interestingly enough when I run the hg@bit... command on the client node I am prompted for a password, I press enter and it fails.

I've cat'd the files both local and client and can confirm they are correct.
I'm running as root on client node and have placed the keys in /root/.ssh, again verified by pwd.

Running verbose for the hg@bit... command on client again asks for the passphrase, on enter permission is denied.

Any help is hugely appreciated.  Below is the log and the chef recipe, thank you.

```
/root/.ssh
[root@ip-172-22-4-44 .ssh]# ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org -v
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [104.192.143.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_1.0.287-a1d21a7 app-126
debug1: no match: conker_1.0.287-a1d21a7 app-126
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=20 dh_need=20
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=20 dh_need=20
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
[root@ip-172-22-4-44 .ssh]#


    include_recipe 'chef-vault'

#installation of git
package 'git' do
  action :install
end

#declare the vault
gitKey = chef_vault_item(:credentialsGit, 'git')

file "/root/.ssh/id_rsa" do
  content gitKey['git-key']
  mode 0600
  owner node['user']
  action :create
  notifies :run, 'execute[git ssh]', :immediately
end

execute 'git ssh' do
  command 'GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa"'
  user node['user']
end

#pull down the repo
git "/home/ec2-user/spring-app" do
  repository "git@bitbucket.org:sgreen22/emrwebapp.git"
  #I've tried a variety of these using the ext helper as per a guide, but still no good.
  # repository "ext::ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no git@bitbucket.org %S /sgreen22/emrwebapp.git"
  # repository "ext::ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no git@bitbucket.org:sgreen22/emrwebapp.git"
  checkout_branch "master"
  action :sync
  # ssh_wrapper "ssh -i /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa"  #I've tried this but no effect
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a simpler solution to the above, the [`application_git` cookbook](https://github.com/poise/application_git) has a resource that handles all this for you, just provide the `deploy_key` value and it will take care of the rest.

Comment: ...hours of ggogle-fu and this did not show at all.  Sad times.  Thank you for taking the time to post - I need to try the previous answer first to settle the curiosity but this does look far far simpler.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm working on it, a refactored version of the cookbook will be released shortly with hopefully better SEO :)

Comment: You wrote it?  Well, well done :D  I've just literally come to choose the answer as it worked perfectly.  Struggle for another hour or two on the other approach without success.  
one thing I found awkward as a newb was not knowing how to get the lwrp(?) to be invoked but I followed a couple of the examples and noticed the inclusion of build-recipes.  Works perfectly, thankyou!

Comment: I also didn't know about this recipe thats why I put my example there. When I'm back to that I will rework it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how you can update chef repo from GitHub using ssh wrapper.

```
repo = 'emrwebapp'
wrapper = "git_wrapper_#{repo}.sh"

file wrapper do
    owner 'ec2-user'
    group 'ec2-user'
    mode 00755
    content "#!/bin/sh\nexec /usr/bin/ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null "\
    '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no '\
    "-i /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa \"$@\""
end

git repo do
    repository "git@bitbucket.org:sgreen22/#{repo}.git"
    reference 'master'
    ssh_wrapper wrapper
    user 'ec2-user'
    group 'ec2-user'
end
```

At the end you will get `git_wrapper_emrwebapp.sh` file generated with chef that will be used for `ssh_wrapper` for `git resource`.

SSH wrapper file looks like that:

```
#!/bin/sh 
exec /usr/bin/ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa "$@"
```

Comment: Hey glg, so in this example I'd still need to copy the ssh key from the vault to the client and then use the wrapper to invoke that key?  
Also wanted to ask about the /home/ec2-user in your example.  I have to run chef as root as so was putting files that that dir, is there somethign abotu your example that makes that a non-issue or would I just need to replace your home/ec2 with root?

Comment: Hey @null, yes you need to copy the key from your vault still and place it in /home/ec2-user/.ssh or /root/.ssh where you prefer. About the second question: there is nothing specific in that I just see in your example that you are using this path /home/ec2-user and I decide to put this in my example. You can select what ever directory you want and assign  proper permission if you need it.